# Setting Triton to Make LTSAs for Channel 1

Tags: software, ltsa, triton

How to set Triton to only work with channel 1 of my files?

I know a solution would be to split my files, but every time I try, Sox tells me the channels are unreadable and when I load the files into Triton to make an LTSA when it tells me to pick a channel, I cannot see all the channels options, so how can I set Triton to only create LTSAs for channel 1 to bypass these problems?

Comment: Hi @KarianneKapfer! What is the file type of your data and how many channels do you have? For me, when working with either xwavs or wavs, Triton prompts for which channel and then I can choose (in my case from 1-4). Could you clarify what you mean with "cannot see all the channels options"?

Comment: I have between 8-12 channels, WAV files, and yes I get the same prompt but I get the same number repeated across the screen, either 8 or 12 with no other options.

Comment: Could you update your post with this added info (comments can become hidden or deleted over time) as well as what version of Triton you are using, and possible a screenshot of that channel prompt, where it is showing repeated numbers?